# Reactjs set state inside map function

Tags: reactjs

I am mapping json data in reactjs I want to set State inside map function but it is giving error in console "illegal constructor".

```
  {
                  links.get("links").map((data, index) => {

                    if (data.get("type") == "DROPDOWN") {
                      return (


                        <div className="circle" style={{ position: "relative" }} onClick={() => {

                         _this.setState({
                          openDrawer: !_this.state.openDrawer
                         })
                        }}>
                          <div className="aligner">
                            <span className="fa fa-plane"></span>
                            <span style={{ position: "absolute", top: "48px" }} >{data.get("name")}</span>
                          </div>
                        </div>

                      )
                    }
```

Comment: which is the line in which you are getting the error? can you add the error screen shot?

Comment: @PraveenRaoChavan.G i am getting error when i click on button

Comment: @owaislatif hope your code is inside render(), then why your referring _this to setState ? check this once https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-aensbd !

Answer (score 0):

you need to bind the context like this:

```
 {
              links.get("links").map((data, index) => {

                if (data.get("type") == "DROPDOWN") {
                  return (


                    <div className="circle" style={{ position: "relative" }} onClick={() => {

                     _this.setState({
                      openDrawer: !_this.state.openDrawer
                     })
                    }}>
                      <div className="aligner">
                        <span className="fa fa-plane"></span>
                        <span style={{ position: "absolute", top: "48px" }} >{data.get("name")}</span>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                  )
                }.bind(this)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am using ES 6 syntax

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you have a separate handler to set the state like this

```
setOpenDrawerHandler = () => {
 this.setState((prevState,currentPrrops)=>{ return {openDrawer: !prevState.openDrawer} })
}
```

and then use this reference inside **map**

```
<div className="circle" style={{ position: "relative" }} onClick={this.setOpenDrawerHandler }>
```